# App crashes while converting to Objective-C ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm Convert to Objective-C ARC, I am getting error for the below code.

```
ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty));
```

XCode suggests us to change to the below one. Once changed like below there is no error. But the app crashes.

```
ABMultiValueRef phones =(__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty)));
```

What should I do to avoid app crash?

Comment: And the stack trace for the crash…?

Answer (score 2):

Your original code is not correct. You're telling the compiler that it's safe to use a `ABMultiValueRef` as an `NSString` -- and it isn't.

I've not tried this but, something like this might work better:

```
ABMultiValueRef phones =(ABMultiValueRef)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty));
NSString* num = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, 0);
```

Comment: I think it is the other way around. `ABMultiValueRef` is CoreFoundation object, so no bridge is needed at all in the first line. But the return value from `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` must be bridged to `NSString`.

Comment: @MartinR I think you're right (updated the answer). But I think the key is not using the `ABMultiValueRef` as a string -- no matter what flags you add that's wrong and I'm amazed that it worked!